# Deploy MeteorJs app to Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, meteor

I've been trying to deploy a Meteor 1.4.3.2 app to Google App Engine to no avail.

I've tried the following instructions -

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-a-meteor-app-on-google-app-engine-97d340c63576
- https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-meteor-on-google-app-engine
- https://medium.com/@isohaze/how-to-dockerize-a-meteor-1-4-app-120a34089ddb

All of which leave me with the same result -  Error: Can't find npm module 'meteor-deque'

if I install the package manually in programs/server and try to deploy again I get - Error: Can't find npm module 'mongodb'

So I install mongodb manually and finally get Error: Cannot find module './entry.js'

Is there any one out there that has successfully deployed a meteor 1.4.3.2 app on Google App Engine that can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully deployed meteor 1.4+ on GCP and AWS using mup by following the directions [here](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up).

here is a sample mup config I use /Users/dg/Projectname/.deployment/staging/mup.js
The .deployment directory is next to .meteor and is hidden so it is not packaged and sent to the server with the rest of the app.

```js
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '1.2.3.4',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: '/Users/dg/.ssh/mypemfile.pem'
    }
  },
  meteor: {
    name: 'appname',
    path: '../../',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://1.2.3.4/',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/appname'
    },

    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },
  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for posting, I have a couple questions. What do I need to put for the server host and username? I made a PEM file, so those are the only two things I'm not sure about. Also will this work with the Flexible Environment?

Comment: host is the ip address of your server and the username should either be ubuntu or root same as the username you use when you ssh into the server. You should be able to ssh into your server ssh -i ~/.ssh/mypemfile.pem ubuntu@**.***.***.** replacing the asterisk with the ip of your server.

Comment: I got it working on Compute Engine, but have not been successful in getting it on App Engine.

Comment: Hi, were you able to deploy your app? If yes can you please share some details?